# Mmodel spec with has_many :through; How to get it to work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot

I'm having a relation between my activities and clients called "Activityclient"(original, huh?)

Whenever I try to spec my Activity.rb through FactoryGirl I get

```
 1) Activity has valid factory
    Failure/Error: expect(FactoryGirl.build(:activity)).to be_valid
    NoMethodError:
      undefined method `stringify_keys' for #<Activityclient:0x73498b0>
    # ./app/models/activity.rb:52:in `block in activityclients='
    # ./app/models/activity.rb:48:in `each'
    # ./app/models/activity.rb:48:in `activityclients='
    # C:in `object'
    # ./spec/models/activity_spec.rb:5:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>
```

My activity Factory is:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activity do
        title { "Activity" }
        group_id { "1" }
        url { "http://www.abc.com/"} 
        activityclients {[FactoryGirl.create(:activityclient)]}
        client {FactoryGirl.create(:client)}
    end
end
```

And my Activityclient factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activityclient do
        start_date {Date.parse('2013-05-13 12:00:00')}
        end_date {Date.parse('2013-05-13 12:15:00')}
        group_id { 1 }
    end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,

**edit:** Editted after @Vee's suggestion. Same error though

Answer (score 0):

Some of the "supposed to be" attributes are being treated as methods in your `activity` and `activityclient` factories.

Update `activity` factory with the following:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activity do
        title { "Activity" }
        group_id { "1" }
        url { "http://www.abc.com/"} 
        activityclients {[FactoryGirl.create(:activityclient)]}
        client {FactoryGirl.create(:client)}
    end
end
```

Note how `title`, `group_id` and `url` are set using `{...}`.  Also ensure the same in `activityclient` factory for `group_id` attribute:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activityclient do
        start_date {Date.parse('2013-05-13 12:00:00')}
        end_date {Date.parse('2013-05-13 12:15:00')}
        group_id { 1 }
    end
end
```

A few other suggestions:

When you are within a factory girl factory(rather, when `factory_girl` is already required) you don't need to spell out `FactoryGirl.create`, you could just call `create`.  Second, instead of doing `Date.parse` supplying timepart, which gets ignored since you're using Date class.  You should be using either `Time` or `DateTime`.

With these your factories would look like follows (note the following example uses `DateTime`, you could use `Time` if you'd like):

```
# activity
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activity do
        title { "Activity" }
        group_id { 1 }
        url { "http://www.abc.com/"} 
        activityclients { [ create(:activityclient) ] }
        client { create(:client) }
    end
end

#activityclient
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activityclient do
        start_date { DateTime.now.midnight }
        end_date { DateTime.now.midnight.change(min: 15) }
        group_id { 1 }
    end
end
```

To ensure the associations are set correctly update your factory definitions to use [`callbacks`](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/get-your-callbacks-on-with-factory-girl-3-3) as:

```
# activity
FactoryGirl.define do
    factory :activity do
        title { "Activity" }
        group_id { 1 }
        url { "http://www.abc.com/"} 

        after(:create) do |a|
          a.activityclients << create(:activityclient)
          a.client { create(:client) }
        end
    end
end
```

Also, update the assignments of `activityclient` to `a.activityclients` with:

```
a.activityclients << create(:activityclient)
```

instead of assigning an array with `a.activityclients { [ create(:activityclient) ] }`.  With the former, FactoryGirl assigns and saves the association whereas with the latter although the array is assigned the association is not saved.

**Update:**

The `after(:create)` callback will only execute if you are creating your factories using `FactoryGirl.create...` in your specs.  If you are only building them using `FactoryGirl.build` then you should replace `after(:create)` with `after(:build)`.  Please refer to [`FactoryGirl callbacks`](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/get-your-callbacks-on-with-factory-girl-3-3) for further details.

Comment: Hmm; Still not working. Every time I do `FactoryGirl.build(:activity)` it gives the stringify error on `Activityclients`

Comment: Activityclient.rb has `belongs_to :activity` and `belongs_to :client`. Client.rb `has_many :activityclients` and `has_many :activities, through: :activityclients`

Same goes for :activity

Comment: `activity_client` gives `Factory not registered: activity_client`

Comment: @CaptainCarl, correct.  Since your class name is `Activityclient` (with a lowercase `c`), you wouldn't need to change the name.  I've updated my answer to use `after(:create)` callback, please give that a try.

Comment: Thanks. It results in `undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass` on the `to be_valid` unfortunately.

Comment: My bad, update `a.activityclients { [ create(:activityclient) ] }` with `a.activityclients << create(:activityclient)`

Comment: Still the same. Tried same method on create(:client) aswell. Think it has to do with methods in my Activity.rb that don't know how to work with the a. stuff. The error occurs in one of my methods in Activity.rb (`if (activityclients.last[:start_date].to_i > activityclients.last[:end_date].to_i)`)

Comment: @CaptainCarl, that's pretty much I've got with the information.  The factories should work with the proposed definition.  How does your failing test look?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45622/discussion-between-captaincarl-and-vee)